# How can I write a custom fields serializer only update specified fields?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How can I write a custom fields serializer only update specified fields ?

I have a Model:

```
class TodoList(models.Model):

    content = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name="todolists")
    is_finish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    uptime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I only want to update the `is_finish` field:

```
class TodoListUpdateIsFinishSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TodoList
        fields = ["id", "is_finish"]
```

In my view:

```
class TodoListUpdateIsFinishAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = TodoListUpdateIsFinishSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = TodoList.objects.all()
```

But when I access this view, there comes issue:

> Expected view TodoListUpdateIsFinishAPIView to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

I tried add `lookup_field = "id"` or `lookup_field = "pk"`, but still not work.

---

**EDIT**
My urlpatterns is bellow:

```
url(r'^todolist/update_isfinish/$', TodoListUpdateIsFinishAPIView.as_view(), name='todolist-update_isfinish')
```

Comment: show the url for this view

Comment: @Linovia What do you mean, my friend?

Comment: na, forget it. @Exprator got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url(r'^todolist/update_isfinish/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', TodoListUpdateIsFinishAPIView.as_view(), name='todolist-update_isfinish')
```

use this url as django need the url parameter to update